# If $X_1$ is independent of $Y_1$ and $X_2$ is independent of $Y_2$, is $X_1 X_2$ independent of $Y_1 Y_2$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, independence

Let $X_1,X_2,Y_1,Y_2$ be random variables defined on the same probability space.

If $X_1$ is independent of $Y_1$ and $X_2$ is independent of $Y_2$, is $X_1 X_2$ independent of $Y_1 Y_2$ ?
If it is true, is it a consequence of a more general result about $\sigma$-algebras ? Something like $f(X_1,X_2)$ is independent of $g(Y_1,Y_2)$ for all measurable $f,h$ ?

Comment: Suppose $Y_2=X_1$ and $Y_1=X_2$  and that $X_1,X_2$ are independent.